# Are there conventions for Python module comments?

Tags: python, module, comments, conventions

It is my understanding that a module docstring should just provide a general description of what a module does and details such as author and version should only be contained in the module's comments.

However, I have seen the following in comments **and** docstrings:

```
__author__ = "..."
__version__ = "..."
__date__ = "..."
```

Where is the correct location to put items such as these? What other `__[name]__` variables are common to list at the top of modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are merely conventions, albeit quite widely-used conventions. See [this description](http://jaynes.colorado.edu/PythonGuidelines.html#module_formatting) of a set of Python metadata requirements.

`__version__` is mentioned in the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Regarding docstrings, there's a [PEP just for you](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)!

> The docstring for a module should
>   generally list the classes, exceptions
>   and functions (and any other objects)
>   that are exported by the module, with
>   a one-line summary of each. (These
>   summaries generally give less detail
>   than the summary line in the object's
>   docstring.) The docstring for a
>   package (i.e., the docstring of the
>   package's **init**.py module) should
>   also list the modules and subpackages
>   exported by the package.

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at:

- [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/), more specifically its pre-defined [fields](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-fields.html).
- [Pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest not to worry about `__author__`, `__version__`, etc. Those attributes are handled by any decent version control system anyway. Only add them if you need to have that information on a production system, where the source code has already been exported out of the version control system.

Comment: But PEP 8 says, that:
 If you have to have Subversion, CVS, or RCS crud in your source file, do it as follows.

__version__ = "$Revision: 84354 $"
# $Source$

These lines should be included after the module's docstring, before any other code, separated by a blank line above and below.